# How to resolve that msys2 fail to update the package database and core system packages

Tags: msys2

Hi I just installed msys2 with exe file that i download through https://www.msys2.org/. So after I installed I was asked to update with comand pacman -Syu However I fail to do Here I compile together the output on the msys2 shell

---

$ pacman -Syuu
:: Synchronizing package databases...
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from mirror.yandex.ru : Could not resolve host: mirror.yandex.ru
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn : Could not resolve host: mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from mirrors.ustc.edu.cn : Could not resolve host: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from mirror.bit.edu.cn : Could not resolve host: mirror.bit.edu.cn
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from mirror.selfnet.de : Could not resolve host: mirror.selfnet.de
error: failed to update mingw32 (invalid url for server)
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw64.db' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw64.db' from sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw64.db' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw64.db' from mirror.yandex.ru : Could not resolve host: mirror.yandex.ru
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw64.db' from mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn : Could not resolve host: mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw64.db' from mirrors.ustc.edu.cn : Could not resolve host: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw64.db' from mirror.bit.edu.cn : Could not resolve host: mirror.bit.edu.cn
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw64.db' from mirror.selfnet.de : Could not resolve host: mirror.selfnet.de
error: failed to update mingw64 (invalid url for server)
error: failed retrieving file 'msys.db' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'msys.db' from sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'msys.db' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
error: failed retrieving file 'msys.db' from mirror.yandex.ru : Could not resolve host: mirror.yandex.ru
error: failed retrieving file 'msys.db' from mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn : Could not resolve host: mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn
error: failed retrieving file 'msys.db' from mirrors.ustc.edu.cn : Could not resolve host: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
error: failed retrieving file 'msys.db' from mirror.bit.edu.cn : Could not resolve host: mirror.bit.edu.cn
error: failed retrieving file 'msys.db' from mirror.selfnet.de : Could not resolve host: mirror.selfnet.de
error: failed to update msys (invalid url for server)
error: failed to synchronize all databases

Comment: Is there a corporate firewall or do you use a proxy to connect to the Internet?

Comment: Thank you are right. The problem solved once I change my internet connection.

Comment: I got `error: failed retrieving file 'mingw64.db' from sourceforge.net`. Solved it by running `/usr/bin/update-ca-trust`. Reference: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/31810458/.